# reference variable in angular2 is not working as expected

Tags: angular, ref

```
       <input type='text' #heroInput><p>{{heroInput.value}}</p>
```

Here the heroInput.value is not getting me the value inside text.

Answer (score 1):

Using ngModel is the way to go here:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="heroInput"><p>{{heroInput}}</p>
```

Comment: Agree I can use two way binding but then what's the use of reference variable?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type='text' #heroInput (keyup)="0"><p>{{heroInput.value}}</p>
```

Comment: why this is required

Comment: you need an event to  detect the change and update the UI but the event doesn't do anything

Comment: you need the event to detect the changes happened to the reference variable